# preg_match regex string

Tags: regex, preg-match

What would be the regex to match all three of the SKUs below?

```
EPUBRISKSPANISH
PUBRISKSPANISH
PUBRMESPANISH
```

I need to match these trhee strings at the end of the string.

```
/$SPANISH/
```

doesn't work in the regex tester, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you need to pull out all the matches:

```
preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z]+SPANISH\b/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to place the `$` at the end of the pattern:

```
/SPANISH$/
```

The pattern you had would try to match the end of the string, followed by "SPANISH", which is impossible.